# Remove a node from the following XML.

Tags: asp.net, .net, xml, vb.net, infragistics

This is the xml I got as an output from the `WriteXmlString()` of `Infragistics ultrawebtree`. I am using this to create another `Infragistics ultrawebtree` with the same structure. But here I don't want the `<Url>something.aspx..</Url>`. I want that to be like this `<Url><\Url>`. So how I can able to remove. This I get as a String. So I used `Regex.Replace()`. But it will work for certain conditions,but for some case it will destruct the xml by deleting some xml tags and xml became not valid due to missing of tags.
I used this expression `<Url>\S*</Url>` to avoid the contents of Url.  Any help will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
- <InfragisticsServerTree XmlVersion="1.0">
  - <uwtModule>
    - <ProjectProperties>
      <ComponentTarget>ClassicTree</ComponentTarget>
      <BrowserTarget>Auto</BrowserTarget>
    </ProjectProperties>
    - <TreeProperties>
      <MaxDataBindDepth>-1</MaxDataBindDepth>
      <Name>uwtModule</Name>
      <Indentation>20</Indentation>
      <SubMenuImage>igNone</SubMenuImage>
      <LoadOnDemandPrompt>
        <b>Loading...</b>
      </LoadOnDemandPrompt>
      <ExpandAnimation>Decelerate</ExpandAnimation>
      <ExpandOnClick>false</ExpandOnClick>
      <CompactRendering>false</CompactRendering>
      <RenderAnchors>false</RenderAnchors>
      - <Style>
        <ForeColor>-16777216</ForeColor>
        <BorderColor>-4144960</BorderColor>
        <BorderStyle>None</BorderStyle>
        <BorderWidth>1px</BorderWidth>
        - <Font>
          <Name>Arial</Name>
          - <Names>
            <Name>Arial</Name>
          </Names>
          <Size>11px</Size>
        </Font>
        <Height>425px</Height>
        <Width>97%</Width>
        - <Padding>
          <Top>5px</Top>
          <Left>5px</Left>
          <Right>5px</Right>
          <Bottom>5px</Bottom>
        </Padding>
      </Style>
      - <SelectedNodeStyle>
        <BackColor>-2894893</BackColor>
        <ForeColor>-16777216</ForeColor>
        - <Padding>
          <Top>2px</Top>
          <Left>2px</Left>
          <Right>2px</Right>
          <Bottom>2px</Bottom>
        </Padding>
      </SelectedNodeStyle>
    </TreeProperties>
    <Styles />
    - <Levels>
      - <Level>
        <Number>0</Number>
      </Level>
    </Levels>
- <Nodes>
  - <Node>
    <Text>123</Text>
    <Url>ModuleEdit.aspx?ModuleID=965</Url>
    <Target>main</Target>
    <Tag>965</Tag>
    <Title>AccptChangesPerfPM</Title>
    <Expanded>true</Expanded>
    - <Nodes>
      - <Node>
        <Text>111</Text>
        <Url>123.aspx?e=965 </Url>
        <Target>main</Target>
        <Tag>TL_-99999</Tag>
      </Node>
      - <Node>
        <Text>werrv</Text>
        <Url>1dfee.aspx?qwe=9er65</Url>
        <Target>main</Target>
        <Tag>12DDfe</Tag>
      </Node>
      - <Node>
        <Text>q2233</Text>
        <Target>main</Target>
        <Tag>TL_1015</Tag>
        <Title>Topic_1</Title>
        <ShowExpand>true</ShowExpand>
        - <Nodes>
          - <Node>
            <Text>T1</Text>
            <Url>w3345_954y65.aspx?ID=965er</Url>
            <Target>main</Target>
            - <Style>
              <ForeColor>-16777216</ForeColor>
            </Style>
            <Tag>82355</Tag>
            <Title>T1</Title>
          </Node>
          - <Node>
            <Text>T2</Text>
            <Url>23_7811.aspx?ID=3u65</Url>
            <Target>main</Target>
            - <Style>
              <ForeColor>-16777216</ForeColor>
            </Style>
            <Tag>82356</Tag>
            <Title>T2</Title>
          </Node>
          - <Node>
            <Text>T3</Text>
            <Url>we456_9.aspx?ID=4r56</Url>
            <Target>main</Target>
            - <Style>
              <ForeColor>-16777216</ForeColor>
            </Style>
            <Tag>82357</Tag>
            <Title>T3</Title>
          </Node>
        </Nodes>
      </Node>
    </Nodes>
  </Node>
</Nodes>
  </uwtModule>
</InfragisticsServerTree>
```

Comment: Changing to Xml class would be easier. 
Did you consider such alternative?

Comment: i tried Regex,xml to DataSet. But I don't have an idea how to work with XMLDoc and XML . I also tried but <Nodes> will be coming under <Node>. <Node> is the child node of <Nodes>. So how i will do querying ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My advice is ignore regular expressions.

Go For XML class's of VB to read it from file,
then work with the nodelists and nodes.

Here are some links to get you starting:

[Create XML in VB#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms760231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Modify XML literals in VB#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb918016.aspx)

[Samples of multiple actions on XML files in VB#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301233)

[[VB.NET] XML - Create and Merge Files. Edit, Add and Delete Nodes.](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=478692)

In the links above you'll find heavy documentation and samples how to open, edit, create, merge.

Below its a how to do what you asked above.:
But with a fair warning: This is C# you'll need to use the above links to convert as i'm not much of a VB.Net developer

```
string path = "./"; //your own path
string name = "Tempo"; //filename
XmlDocument f = new XmlDocument();
f.Load(path + name + ".xml");
XmlNodeList a = f.GetElementsByTagName("Url");
for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
{
    a[i].InnerText = ""  //This had the data inside <Url>...</Url>
}
    f.Save(path+name); //Edited to add the save
```

Comment: Opening a file loading it to a structure search it adapting saving the full file is never a light operation when the XML are big.

But i don't think going with Regex is simpler, yet i have no data to back up my opinion.

Comment: i am not saving to file. I am handling it in a string.

Comment: Well saves a bit in performance.
You can try time both the Regex if you achieved to complete it and this method to compare.

Comment: you can do f.Load(string) also btw